# Define PHP string literal with $ as data

Tags: php, variables

How do i define this variable?

```
$smsTabale = "CRONUS International Ltd_$Message Log";
```

Comment: too late for it but maybe will help to some in future:
you can use ${$variable} inside 
$smsTabale = "CRONUS International Ltd_{$Message} Log";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add \ before $

```
$smsTabale = "CRONUS International Ltd_\$Message Log";
```